# What's china blue?

Tags: colors

Is china blue just jean blue, inspired by the color of uniform of Chinese workers? And how common is china blue in daily conversations and writings? I've only heard this in the song, Vincent (Starry, starry night.)

Comment: I think it comes from porcelain , *china blue*: a bright greenish blue. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/china+blue. "***Blue and white wares***" (Chinese: 青花; pinyin: qīng-huā; literally: "Blue flowers") designate white pottery and porcelain decorated under the glaze with a blue pigment, generally cobalt oxide.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_and_white_porcelain

Comment: Agreed, @Josh61: “I find it harder and harder every day to live up to my blue china.”—Oscar Wilde.

Comment: It's just a standard name for a color, and the process used to produce it.  The term has been used for decades, at least.  See https://books.google.com/books?id=wigoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA64&dq=%22china+blue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ieubVZuqFIGnyASgtb6IDA&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22china%20blue%22&f=false

Comment: OED's first citation is *Wives & Daughters* (1866) by  E. C. Gaskell  - *Her eyes were soft, large, and **china-blue** in colour.*

Answer (score 2):

For an example of 'china blue', see Wedgwood Queens ware.  It's a pale blue that you could easily imagine as the color of a person's eyes.